# AngularJS route won't load the view and reports no errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the structure:

[image: Here is the structure]

Here are the sources:

```js
/* @flow */
"use strict";
(function () {
  const app = angular.module('Lesson2', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'] );
  app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/what', { controller:'FavoCtrl', templateURL:'pages/what.html'})
      .when('/where', { controller:'FavoCtrl', templateURL:'pages/where.html'})
      .otherwise({redirectTo:'/what'});
  });
  app.controller('FavoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.favouriteThings=[
      {what:'raindrops', by:'on', where:'roses'},
      {what:'whiskers', by:'on', where:'mittens'},
      {what:'Brown paper packages', by:'tied up with', where:'strings'},
      {what:'schnitzel', by:'with', where:'noodles'},
      {what:'Wild geese', by:'that fly with', where:'the moon on their wings'},
      {what:'girls', by:'in', where:'white dresses'},
      {what:'Snowflakes', by:'that stay on', where:'my nose and eyelashes'}
    ];
  })

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Lesson2">
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lesson 2</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello!
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

And two "what.html" and "where.html" are plain texts, like `This is "where.html"`

The hardest thing here is that browser does not throw any error, console is clean. Views are not loaded, all I see is "Hello" of "index.html"

Comment: The URL is changed to `/what`?

Comment: @shal It is `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo, in your config block, use **templateUrl** instead of **templateURL**.

It should look like:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
  .when('/what', { controller:'FavoCtrl', templateUrl:'pages/what.html'})
  .when('/where', { controller:'FavoCtrl', templateUrl:'pages/where.html'})
  .otherwise({redirectTo:'/what'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo in your route configuration, it is "templateUrl" and not "templateURL".

If this doesn't solve your problem try adding the controller in your index.html

```
<html ng-app="Lesson2" ng-controller="FavoCtrl">
```